# Parametrize plane and get surface area

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Find a parametrization of the surface: $y + 2z = 2$ inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Then, compute its surface area.

I'm having trouble finding the parametrization of the surface. I don't think it's just $<u, v, 1 - \frac12v>$, but don't know how to relate it to the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

Write the equation for the plane using cylindrical coordinates: $y+2z=2\implies \rho\sin{\phi}+2z=2$. Solving for $z$ we have,

$$z(\rho,\phi)=\frac{2-\rho\sin{\phi}}{2},~~\text{where}~0\leq\rho\leq1,~0\leq\phi\leq2\pi.$$

Then the surface parametrization is $$\vec{r}(\rho,\phi)=\langle\rho\cos{\phi},\rho\sin{\phi},\frac{2-\rho\sin{\phi}}{2}\rangle.$$

Comment: So now to compute its surface area I get that the crossproduct of the partials is $\frac12 \rho$. My question is do I integrate this with respect to just $d\rho d\phi$?

Comment: @user127778 That's it.

Comment: @user127778 However, after finishing the calculations I got a different value for the norm of the cross product. Should be $\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\rho$ instead of $\frac12\rho$.

Comment: yea you're right thanks